# Set up a new font family

Tags: fonts, fontfamily

Can anyone tell me which font family is applied like this picture and how to set it to a LaTex document? Thank you all so much!
[image]

Comment: Would you please be so kind and add the text to be typeset? Few of us are acquainted with Vietnamese and looking character by character would be painful.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have the PDF File

Comment: You should be able to copy the text from the PDF and paste it here. Also, you should be able to identify the font that is used in the PDF. For example, using Acrobat Reader, you can go to the file properties and look up the embedded fonts.

Comment: Copy paste is restricted in this file though

Comment: @HưngTrần Just type in the text, so we can copy-paste it.

Comment: @egreg According to your humble thought is my answer right? I have a suspect that the x is very attached to the 3.

Comment: If you have the pdf file you do not  need to ask us to guess from an image, the first comment has links to an answer that lets you get an exact list of fonts used.

Answer (score 3):

For my humble opinion it is `TeX Gyre Schola font`. See the image below. In addendum I not am able to write in Vietnamese language. This code is compilable with the engine `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[bb=boondox]{mathalfa}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/greek,Scale=.8]{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\begin{document}
Cho hàm số $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$
\[
y=\frac{3x+1}{x-1} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. thank you so much

Comment: @HưngTrần I have a suspect that the x is very attached to the 3 and I am not able to separate the 3 a little bit from the x.

Comment: This seems good, but you shouldn't load `fontenc`